# Comparison Operators 'equal' is not working

Tags: php

I am validating a condition for

```
$time = $user['time_send'];
$chk_date   = date('Y-m-d H:i');  
var_dump($time == $chk_date);
```

But I am getting `bool(false)` as output.

Comment: Can you show `$time` data?

Comment: Are you sure `$time` is the same format as `$chk_date`?

Comment: $time = 2014-03-7 15:14 and $chk_date = 2014-03-07 15:14

Comment: date('Y-m-d H:i') = 2014-03-07. "07", not "7" Change to date('Y-m-j H:i')

Comment: time data is not correct perhaps, if you think they are same and still not working then use trim() $time = trim($user['time_send']);

Comment: I don't really know why we answer such questions - a simple echo/var_dump of both values would have been enough to find out the problem by himself!

Comment: thanks  @cornelb,it work.

Answer (score 2):

```
$time = '2014-03-7 15:14';
$chk_date = '2014-03-07 15:14';
if(strtotime($time) == strtotime($chk_date)){
   echo 'hola';
}else{
   echo 'hello';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.i'll keep this in mind.

Comment: sorry. your solution is not working.

Comment: what do you want to do ? the above condition echos 'hola'

Comment: no need of ur extra comment. i have done.@abbiya

Comment: you asked for it. chill dude. peace

Comment: just asked for solution not ur stupid comment @abbiya